# Plot triangular mesh from list of (x,y,z) points in input text file

Tags: matlab, plot, import, wolfram-mathematica, mesh

I am trying to use Mathematica to plot a triangular mesh by use the list of (x,y,z) coordinates from an input file.

The format of the input file is like so. Each three lines of co-ordinates defines one triangular element of the mesh.

- 1 -2 -3
- 4 -5 -6
- 7 -8 -9
- 10 -11 -12
- 13 -14 -15
- 16 -17 -18
  etc etc..."

I was planning on using the "Triangle[{{p11,p12,p13},…}]" function in mathematica to plot each triangle but I am unsure how to code mathematica to open my input file, and import the point coordinates into the plot function in the correct format.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Also, I have access to matlab which may be easy to complete this task.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [Delaunay Triangulation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html)?

Comment: you have lumped together a bunch of unrelated questions, which is not a good way to get good answers on this site.  " I am unsure how to code mathematica to open my input file"  ... see `Import`

Comment: Why is this tagged `matlab` if you're using Mathematica?

Comment: @Szabolcs I got confused with that too. The end of the question says _Also, I have access to matlab which may be easy to complete this task._